# ImplicitRegion and Nearest

Tags: computational-geometry

It is known how to make Voronoi diagram using `DensityPlot` and `Nearest`.
I assumed that it is possible to use `ImplicitRegion` instead of `DensityPlot`,
but the next code not work:

```
n = 7; pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
r = ImplicitRegion[First@Nearest[pts, {x, y}] == pts[[1]], {x, y}]
```

The Output is `EmptyRegion[2]` always.